# How to close the gap between a scaled down iframe and the next element?

Tags: html, css

[image]

I have an iframe that I scaled down to 65% but even though it has shrunk, the "div" still occupies 100% of the original iframe size and as a result, there is a huge gap between the iframe and the next element. I don't know to close the gap. I want the next element to be right underneath the embedded iframe.
HTML code:

```css
@media only screen and (min-width:768px){
  .container-iframe{
    -moz-transform: scale(0.65, 0.65); 
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.65, 0.65); 
    -o-transform: scale(0.65, 0.65);
    -ms-transform: scale(0.65, 0.65);
    transform: scale(0.65, 0.65); 
    -moz-transform-origin: center;
    -webkit-transform-origin: center;
    -o-transform-origin: center;
    -ms-transform-origin: center;
    transform-origin: center;
  }
  .iframe-responsive{
    bottom: 0;
    float: center;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position:absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container-iframe">
    <iframe class="iframe-responsive" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/chw2oMUrh4U"></iframe>
</div>  
<div class="row">
  <div class="col" style="text-align: center;">
    <h1>Something 1</h1> 
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col" style="text-align: center;">
    <h1>Something 2</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a reason for using scaling as opposed to setting width 65%?

Answer (score 0):

You could give your `.container-iframe` a set height. Currently the container has no height and the iframe has nothing as reference for the 100% you gave to it.

```css
@media only screen and (min-width:768px){
  .container-iframe{
    -moz-transform: scale(0.65, 0.65); 
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.65, 0.65); 
    -o-transform: scale(0.65, 0.65);
    -ms-transform: scale(0.65, 0.65);
    transform: scale(0.65, 0.65); 
    -moz-transform-origin: center;
    -webkit-transform-origin: centeer;
    -o-transform-origin: center;
    -ms-transform-origin: center;
    transform-origin: center;
    height: 150px;
  }
  .iframe-responsive{
    bottom: 0;
    float: center;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position:absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container-iframe">
    <iframe class="iframe-responsive" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/chw2oMUrh4U"></iframe>
</div>  
<div class="row">
  <div class="col" style="text-align: center;">
    <h1>Something 1</h1> 
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col" style="text-align: center;">
    <h1>Something 2</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question but it did not work, the gap is still the same. Before posting this question, I tried to change the height several times but to no avail. The height stubbornly remains the same.

Comment: Are you aware of your media query? It only displays if your screen is bigger than `768px`. In the small preview there is a gap but not in the big one.

Comment: my browser still shows a big gap and my screen is bigger than 1240px